# Node.js function async return not awaiting

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I think I am having a problem understanding the await/promises in Node.js, I thought I was implementing it correctly but it does not look right...

I have this function to get a list of files from my Google Drive:

```
const listFiles = async () => {
    const filesList = await googleDrive.listFiles();
    filesList.forEach((file)=>{
        console.log(`File is ${file.name}`);
    });
    return filesList;
  }
```

This function works fine, but now I tried to call it like this in my main.js:

```
const listFiles = async () => {
    const filesList = await googleDrive.listFiles();
    filesList.forEach((file)=>{
        console.log(`File is ${file.name} with id`);
    });
    return filesList;
  }

const getFiles =() =>{
    const files = listFiles();
    console.log(files);
};


getFiles();
```

So my problem here is that, from `getFiles()`I always get `Promise { <pending> }` as a console.log...but in my `listFiles()`, I can see the files being printed correctly after the `await`....I do not really get it, after the `await`, the `filesList` should be ready and resolved.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async` function [returns a promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), so you still have to `await` it

> Return value
>
> A Promise which will be resolved with the value returned by the async function, or rejected with an exception thrown from, or uncaught within, the async function.

```
const listFiles = async () => {
    const filesList = await googleDrive.listFiles();
    filesList.forEach((file)=>{
        console.log(`File is ${file.name} with id`);
    });
    return filesList;
  }

const getFiles = async () =>{
    const files = await listFiles();
    console.log(files);
};


getFiles();
```

Comment: ok thanks, now I guess getFiles also will return a promise, and again when i call it i will have to await, and over and over again, correct?

Comment: @codeKiller yeah, if in this case there is no task need to be executed sequentially after `getFiles()`, you could still call it this way

Comment: Use .then & .catch when calling getFiles() . This is what I follow , all async await code , but the last one .then & .catch . If you don't catch the error , you will get "unhandled promise rejection" error when ever you have any error inside getFiles function.

Answer (score 1):

`listFiles` is correctly listed as being `async`, but in this case, `getFiles` should be async too - it needs to `await` the results of `listFiles`.

Your code should then look as follows:

```js
const listFiles = async () => {
    const filesList = await googleDrive.listFiles();
    filesList.forEach((file)=>{
        console.log(`File is ${file.name} with id`);
    });
    return filesList;
  }

const getFiles = async () =>{
    const files = await listFiles();
    console.log(files);
};


getFiles();
```